# how to show tabs dynamic in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have three tables category, subcategory, subsubcategory.

```
category table
cat_id   name        cat_status
15      Electronic      1
16      Fashion         1

subcategory table
subcat_id     cat_id        name        subcat_status
10              15           Lcd                1
11              15           Mobile             1
12              16           Men                1
13              16           Women              1
14              16           SunGlass           1
15              16           Footwear           1

subsubcat_id   subcat_id     cat_id        name       subsubcat_status
12             12            16             Shirt                1
13             13            16             Shirt                1
14             11            15             Andriod              1
15             11            15             Iphone               1
16             13            15             Windoews             1
17             11            15             Sonny                1
18             14            16             Flymachine           1
19             15            16             Nike                 1
```

My home page dynamic tab which contains category
Home Electronics Fashion Contact

After click on Electronics, new page tabs shows
Home Lcd Mobile contact (lcd and mobile are subcategory)

After click on Mobile tabs new page tabs open
Home Andriod windoews Iphone

tabs open and product shown according their cat_id,subcat_id,subsubcat_id

Comment: What have you tried in order to get this working?  What code do you currently have and what's not working about it?

Comment: **Android** not *Andriod*, **Windows** not  *Windoews*, **iPhone** not *Iphone*...

Answer (score 0):

use join table

```
SELECT category.id, subcat.id, subsubcat.id FROM subsubcat INNER JOIN subcat on subsubcat.id_subcat=subcat.id INNER JOIN category ON subcat.id_category=category.id order by subsubcat.id;
```

but, you should make relation of table on your three table. category have child subcategory, subcatogory have child subsubcategory. so, if id of subsubcategory was called, subcat id and category id will be called too.

sorry for my english. i hope you will understand.